# Product images are not visible on listing page as well as detail page

Tags: magento

In my magento site product images are not visible.
I have images for all the products uploaded and set to **Base, small** and **thumbnail** images.

My media folder permission is 777.

Still I am getting error like this

```
    NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dev.myproject.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/250x300/
4e8686d859209b8b568b3ce08d7279f7/A/T/ATCEAR-9_2.jpg
```

in Firefox console.

This folder **small_image**  is not at the specified location. 
least placeholder images are also not loading.
I can not run `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` in root of site(I tried this but got a blank page).
So I do not have information about gd library exists or not?

What may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your all type of cache (var/cache, Image cache) . So when you clear your cache memory then magento will create cache again that you visited products images. Image cache is located at your media directory, In your posted link above

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dev.myproject.com/media/catalog/product/**cache**/1/small_image/250x300/
4e8686d859209b8b568b3ce08d7279f7/A/T/ATCEAR-9_2.jpg
```

You can see the cache directory. You can delete that directly or from magento admin section, by visiting admin section--> System--> Cache management--> select all cache then delete.

Then check again .And make sure your images are exist first..

Comment: Through admin I have already cleared the caches and flush catalog images cache.

Comment: I have tried deleting the cache folder.Still problem persists.

Comment: Disable cache..so your page images will load by direct link. Then check again..make sure you set permission for all directories and sub directories and images...Not only the media directory..

Comment: I have disable images still getting same image url in the console

Comment: Can you post your site url here ..?

Comment: At least placeholder images are loaded or not ..?Instead of product images..If not its probably Permission issues ..

Comment: have you installed any external cache, like memcache or APC? then login to server and clear that cache also.